# Verifying eth_call Results with Cryptographic Proofs for L1s and L2s

Tags: contract-invocation, zksnark, zero-knowledge, eth-call, zkevm

I'm interested in enhancing the reliability of static call requests (`eth_call`) to Ethereum smart contracts.  Currently, the returned data is only as trustworthy as the node or service providing it. Could cryptographic proofs offer a more robust solution?

My ideal scenario:

- **Proof with the Result:** When making an `eth_call`(to for example get an AMM quote, or DeFi loan interest rate), a proof accompanies the returned data. This proof attests to the result's correctness based on the smart contract logic and the blockchain state at the specified block height.
- **L1 Considerations:** For L1s, proofs could leverage the PoS consensus mechanism and quorum certificates to verify a historical state root.
- **L2 Focus:** In zkEVM rollups, proofs could be tied to the validity/zk proofs submitted to L1, ensuring consistency.

Questions:

1. Is this concept of proof-enhanced `eth_call` responses technically feasible on both L1s and  L2s?
2. How would a client/interface retrieve and verify these proofs?
3. Are there existing libraries or projects in the Ethereum ecosystem that explore this functionality?
4. What potential challenges or limitations should be anticipated in terms of implementation and adoption?

Comment: For additional context I asked a related but broader [question here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/111146/87217)